# MySQL sum of query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have a table called "trails" inside the table I have 3 columns called "id", "name" and "grading".

I have the following query which gives me the last 5 rows of a specific trail name based on the id. This works perfectly but now I need to get the sum total of the 5 results in the grading column?

```
SELECT * FROM `trails` WHERE `name` = "Free Flow" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(`grading`) FROM (SELECT ...) AS data

Comment: As a side note, ordering by an `id` column is often meaningless.  It _might_ be the insertion order, but this isn't actually guaranteed.  And since db ids have no real meaning to the world outside, why would anybody else care about ordering by id?  What do you mean by "last 5 rows"?  Last 5 inserted - do you have a timestamp to record this?  Last 5 with activity (ie, a row was updated, changing `grading`)?  Rely on ids for only one thing - uniqueness (that is, only use them in `ORDER BY`s as a way to make sorts stable - you should have something else as the first sort column).

Comment: There will be no updating of rows, only want the last 5 entries which will have a unique incrementing id. It works fine for this small application, thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(`grading`)
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM `trails`
   WHERE `name` = "Free Flow"
   ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) AS TEMP;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this query to get the sum of a particular column

```
SELECT SUM(originalOfferSize)
FROM `ActiveListings`
WHERE `originalOfferSize` = 4000000
ORDER BY `listingId` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I strongly suspect it will sum all rows because groupping happens before limiting (i'm not so sure so i didn't downvote).

Comment: @user2473917 It must be, I think it wouldn't be accepted otherwise.